# If I wasn't invited to the shareholder' meeting but now I do own stock in the company, can I still attend?

Tags: shares, shareholder-meeting

There's a company whose shareholder meeting I'd like to attend. The official notice says that only shareholders of record at a given date are invited and can vote. I acquired shares after that date but before the meeting date. Can I still attend the meeting? I don't want to vote, only ask some questions.

Comment: Does the official notice have any contact details? You're probably best asking the organisers ... the cut-off date may be legal/regulatory, but may be more of a logistical thing.

Comment: If you actually want to get information, you can ask their investor relations department anytime without waiting for a meeting, and regardless of the date you bought. If your goal actually is to confront or embarass the managers as a publicity stunt or similar, you're wasting your time; almost none of the attendees will give a fig, and the handful who do will be as quixotic and ineffective as you.

Comment: Usually everyone is invited who owns shares on date X. The date X may be on the day of the shareholder meeting, or later, or earlier. So it depends on whether you owned the shares before that date, not the date of the invitation.

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on the company law of the jurisdiction. However, in most cases to be a valid shareholder your name needs to be registered in the company's shareholder books. In your case, since you were not registered, there is no provision by which you could be deemed a shareholder and probably will not be able to attend the meeting as a shareholder. The registration on the books is also important for other matters like dividend payment etc.

However, in your case, you may write to the company if you can  be allowed to attend the meeting in other capacity, for example as an observer, however, that would depend on the company law, if it allows such provision and the willingness of the company to accommodate such request.

However, there is no harm asking, you could speak to them and find out.